# Is google play inApp Billing library mandatory for inApp purchases? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, in-app-purchase, upi

Instead of Google inApp Billing library, can I use other forms of payment such as Google Pay, PayTM, or any other UPI payment for inApp purchases?
Of course there are other upi payment libraries such as EasyUPIPayment library, etc, but will Google allow it to upload in Play Store?